# Two backends, one DB - what's the best way to integrate data with Django?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django, ruby, integration

Currently I'm working in a project that will add a functionality to a legacy application.

For a number of reasons that are completely out of my control, this functionality will resides in a different backend.

Not only that, each backend is actually in a different programming language (legacy is ruby, using Rails, new is Python, using Django), and different architectures (legacy is a monolithic app, django will provide a Rest API for a React frontend).

So far, so good. I've already solved how to integrate user's sessions, and mapped each table as a django model using the lifesaver command `python manage.py inspectdb > legacy_models.py`.

Now, I've got a bigger issue in my hands.
Some of the old tables are not normalized, or there're missing fields which I'll need for the new application.
I can't really mess with the old tables and create new fields, alter relationships or anything like that, since this legacy app is maintained by a separate corporation and we can't really depends on changes by their side, nor can we guarantee that changing the old tables won't mess with anything in this application.

Therefore, I've took another route, and decided to create tables on Django that'll extend the old tables with the info I'll need.

To make things easier to visualize, just imagine a table like `Employee`, but this table do not have a field `productivity` (that will be calculated in the new application). So I'd create a new table such as `EmployeeDetails` that will contain a OneToOne relationship with employee + any new field I need.

The issue here is:

I'd need to guarantee that any new Employee instance (that are being created in the legacy app) have a EmployeeDetails.

I've thought of two ways to do that:

- Using a Celery Beat Task and a separate DB table to keep track of the last Employee synced, in order to verify if new employees were created.
- Create a Postgres Trigger.

I'm tempted to use the first solution, since it's not possible for it to break anything in the legacy application (I mean, who knows what might happen in the legacy application during this employee trigger...)

I'm seriously not confident about this approach though. This is not how I like to design my backends, but the more I look in the legacy app the more my brain screams `DITCH THE LEGACY, REDO THIS IN DJANGO THE CORRECT WAY`... but well, I'm not allowed to do that...

Any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in the situation described you don't have very many good options, but a celery beat task to ensure the existence of the extra OneToOne will either fire way too often using a ton of resources for nothing, or not fire often enough and there are time delay gaps you have to code for. I'm sure you've also evaluated that modifying the database and adding triggers could have a number of unexpected and undesired effects in the legacy code.

My instinct in the situation is to modify the constructor, but Django really discourages changing Model constructors for various reasons. However, we can still achieve this functionality by connecting to formal signals Django fires off. You'd be looking at a pre-init signal or possibly post-init you'll have to test.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/signals/#pre-init

In theory if you connect code to the pre-init signal of the original model it could call out to extended model table and ensure the relationships necessary exist before any code fires to work with the model. I think this approach would much more closely achieve what you're attempting to enforce without a lot of extra hassle and dead network calls.

Also feel free to tell your boss I personally +1 nuking that legacy app in favor of a properly written Django app. The situation described is one where I'd happily declare technical bankruptcy.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I've got two questions about the signals approach:

1- Will the signal trigger even though the instance was created in a separate application? I've always thought that signals would trigger only by the Django's server requests.

2 - If it does trigger, would it trigger even though the models are unmanaged? (I mean, with the attribute managed = False in the Meta options). At the moment all legacy tables are like that, since we'd never change any of these tables directly.

Thanks man

Comment: The signals will only trigger inside the Django app when the model is instantiated and not when something goes into the DB. However, I'm making the assumption that the legacy application is blind to the new tables you're adding, otherwise we'd simply be altering the tables correct? I might be missing something. But yes this type of enforcement would only be available to the Django application.